# When I use input type="button" a function works well but when I use button  it doesn`t

Tags: javascript, html

I call the same function with those two types of button. With the first it works perfectly but with button it works well at the first but in less than one second it looks like refresh the page.

```
<input type="button" id="bProv" value="filtrar" onclick="filtroP()"/>
<button id="bProv" onclick="filtroP()">filtrar</button>
```

Comment: what does the console have to say?

Comment: @Joseph — Nothing, because the JS will run then the page will reload. The JS control doesn't report on the browser leaving the page through a regular form submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` of a `<button>` element defaults to `submit`, so it will run the JS and then immediately submit the form.

Use `<button type="button" ...` if you don't want form submission.

That said, hard coding a button (which does nothing without JS) goes against the principles of [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (which are part of best practise programming for the WWW).